# key card door problem, it doesnt want to close

Tags: roblox

I edited the script so that it open when i click on it and I have the specyfic tool in my backpack and it work, but I wanted it to open if you have not only card lvl1 but lvl1 and higher so I did it put now it doesn't want to close, it open but when I click the button again it is keep opening mroe and more insted of closeing and idk what can be wrong with it.

```
local bool = false
local CanOpen1 = true
local CanClose1 = false
local AccessDenied = script.Parent.AccessDenied
local AccessGranted = script.Parent.AccessGranted                       
                        --DO NOT EDIT PAST THIS LINE--
function openDoor()
    script.Parent.DoorOpen:play()
    for i = 3,(door.Size.z / 0.15) do
        wait()
        door.CFrame = door.CFrame - (door.CFrame.lookVector * 0.15)
    end
end

function closeDoor()
    script.Parent.DoorClose:play()
    for i = 3,(door.Size.z / 0.15) do
        wait()
        door.CFrame = door.CFrame + (door.CFrame.lookVector * 0.15)
    end
end

script.Parent.Parent.KeycardReader1.ClickDetector.MouseClick:Connect(function(player)
    if player.Backpack:FindFirstChild("[SCP] Card-L1")or player.Backpack:FindFirstChild("[SCP] Card-L2")or player.Backpack:FindFirstChild("[SCP] Card-L3")or player.Backpack:FindFirstChild("[SCP] Card-L4")or player.Backpack:FindFirstChild("[SCP] Card-L5")or player.Backpack:FindFirstChild("[SCP] Card-Omni") and CanOpen1 == true then

        CanOpen1 = false
        AccessGranted:Play()
        wait(0.75)
        openDoor()
        wait(1)
        CanClose1 = true
    elseif player.Backpack:FindFirstChild("[SCP] Card-L1")or player.Backpack:FindFirstChild("[SCP] Card-L2")or player.Backpack:FindFirstChild("[SCP] Card-L3")or player.Backpack:FindFirstChild("[SCP] Card-L4")or player.Backpack:FindFirstChild("[SCP] Card-L5")or player.Backpack:FindFirstChild("[SCP] Card-Omni") and CanClose1 == true then
        CanClose1 = false
        AccessGranted:Play()
        wait(0.75)
        closeDoor()
        wait(1)
        CanOpen1 = true
    elseif not player.Backpack:FindFirstChild("[SCP] Card-L1")or player.Backpack:FindFirstChild("[SCP] Card-L2")or player.Backpack:FindFirstChild("[SCP] Card-L3")or player.Backpack:FindFirstChild("[SCP] Card-L4")or player.Backpack:FindFirstChild("[SCP] Card-L5")or player.Backpack:FindFirstChild("[SCP] Card-Omni") and not bool then
        bool = true
        AccessDenied:Play()
        wait(2)
        bool = false
    end
end)

script.Parent.Parent.KeycardReader2.ClickDetector.MouseClick:Connect(function(player)
    if player.Backpack:FindFirstChild("[SCP] Card-L1")or player.Backpack:FindFirstChild("[SCP] Card-L2")or player.Backpack:FindFirstChild("[SCP] Card-L3")or player.Backpack:FindFirstChild("[SCP] Card-L4")or player.Backpack:FindFirstChild("[SCP] Card-L5")or player.Backpack:FindFirstChild("[SCP] Card-Omni")and CanOpen1 == true then
        CanOpen1 = false
        AccessGranted:Play()
        wait(0.75)
        openDoor()
        wait(1)
        CanClose1 = true
    elseif player.Backpack:FindFirstChild("[SCP] Card-L1")or player.Backpack:FindFirstChild("[SCP] Card-L2")or player.Backpack:FindFirstChild("[SCP] Card-L3")or player.Backpack:FindFirstChild("[SCP] Card-L4")or player.Backpack:FindFirstChild("[SCP] Card-L5")or player.Backpack:FindFirstChild("[SCP] Card-Omni") and CanClose1 == true then
        CanClose1 = false
        AccessGranted:Play()
        wait(0.75)
        closeDoor()
        wait(1)
        CanOpen1 = true
    elseif not player.Backpack:FindFirstChild("[SCP] Card-L1")or player.Backpack:FindFirstChild("[SCP] Card-L2")or player.Backpack:FindFirstChild("[SCP] Card-L3")or player.Backpack:FindFirstChild("[SCP] Card-L4")or player.Backpack:FindFirstChild("[SCP] Card-L5")or player.Backpack:FindFirstChild("[SCP] Card-Omni") and not bool then
        bool = true
        AccessDenied:Play()
        wait(2)
        bool = false
    end
end)
```

[image: screenshot of the door opening]

Answer (score 0):

You should use just one variable for the door open/close checking

Answer (score 0):

```
local bool = false
local Open = false
local AccessDenied = script.Parent.AccessDenied
local AccessGranted = script.Parent.AccessGranted                       
--DO NOT EDIT PAST THIS LINE--
function openDoor()
    script.Parent.DoorOpen:play()
    for i = 3,(door.Size.z / 0.15) do
        wait()
        door.CFrame = door.CFrame - (door.CFrame.lookVector * 0.15)
    end
end
function closeDoor()
    script.Parent.DoorClose:play()
    for i = 3,(door.Size.z / 0.15) do
        wait()
        door.CFrame = door.CFrame + (door.CFrame.lookVector * 0.15)
    end
end
script.Parent.Parent.KeycardReader1.ClickDetector.MouseClick:Connect(function(player)
    if player.Backpack:FindFirstChild("[SCP] Card-L1")or player.Backpack:FindFirstChild("[SCP] Card-L2")or player.Backpack:FindFirstChild("[SCP] Card-L3")or player.Backpack:FindFirstChild("[SCP] Card-L4")or player.Backpack:FindFirstChild("[SCP] Card-L5")or player.Backpack:FindFirstChild("[SCP] Card-Omni") then
        if Open then
            AccessGranted:Play()
            wait(0.75)
            closeDoor()
            wait(1)
            Open = false
        else
            AccessGranted:Play()
            wait(0.75)
            openDoor()
            wait(1)
            Open = true
        elseif not bool then
            bool = true
            AccessDenied:Play()
            wait(2)
            bool = false
        end
    end
end)

script.Parent.Parent.KeycardReader2.ClickDetector.MouseClick:Connect(function(player)
    if player.Backpack:FindFirstChild("[SCP] Card-L1")or player.Backpack:FindFirstChild("[SCP] Card-L2")or player.Backpack:FindFirstChild("[SCP] Card-L3")or player.Backpack:FindFirstChild("[SCP] Card-L4")or player.Backpack:FindFirstChild("[SCP] Card-L5")or player.Backpack:FindFirstChild("[SCP] Card-Omni") then
        if Open then
            AccessGranted:Play()
            wait(0.75)
            closeDoor()
            wait(1)
            Open = false
        else
            AccessGranted:Play()
            wait(0.75)
            openDoor()
            wait(1)
            Open = true
        elseif not bool then
            bool = true
            AccessDenied:Play()
            wait(2)
            bool = false
        end
    end
end)
```